# Android app connection with a MySQL server?

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am fairly new to Android, and I am trying to make a simple backend for an app I am making for fun.

I am wondering what the overall process is when an Android app writes to a MySQL server. From Googling around my tentative understanding is:

Writing:
Android app > user sends input > PHP script receives it > data is entered in MySQL table.

Is this correct? If so, where does the PHP script go? I am planning on using cheap GoDaddy webhosting that comes with 10 x 1 GB MySQL databases as well as domain.

Comment: i guess you have Server written in PHP? so you need to call an PHP GET/POST Url with data to update the MySQL

Comment: You probably need a little more programming experience.